# Extend User Model of FOSUserBundle from abstract class

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony, one-to-many

In Symfony, I'm trying to create a document management system and create relationships to a document.

These documents can belong to a user or to an organization (which also has users). So, similar to github, where a repository can belong to a user  (github.com/iamtheuser/coolrepo) or to an organization (github.com/myorg/coolrepo), this document can belong to a user or an organization.

Now, in order to do this, I've created an abstract class `Documentable`. `Documentable` has the Many-to-One relationship to `Document`. The `Organization` class extends `Documentable` and the `User` class should also extend `Documentable`.

But I'm using FOSUserBundle and I'm having difficulty extending the `User` Model. The original one looks like

```
abstract class User implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    //...
}
```

and I want to somehow extend it like so

```
abstract class User extends Documentable implements UserInterface, GroupableInterface
{
    //...
}
```

The `Documentable` annotation basically looks like:

```
/**

 * Documentable
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="documentable")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentableRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"user" = "AppBundle\Entity\User", "organization" = "AppBundle\Entity\Organization"})
 */
```

I've tried overriding the FOSUserBundle Model several ways, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Are you trying to change FOSUserBundle User class directly? Because this is not the right way. Anyway what error are you getting?

Comment: I've tried overriding the Model / Entity similar to how you would override a controller in Symfony, but it doesn't work, it just takes the Model from the vendor folder. Yes, in a way I want to change it directly, because I want both `Organization` and `User` (from FOSUserBundle) to have the same `Documentable` base class, so I can have a bidirectional relationship, so from the document I can call `$document->getDocumentable()` and it would return `Organization` or `User`.